# Programmatically changing defaultproxy instead of using app.config

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config, desktop-application, defaultproxy

I'm creating a desktop application in WPF. This application uses webclient instances to communicate with an API to collect data from.

In this desktop application I want to create a checkbox which should allow the user to ignore the internet options proxy or to use the default auto detect options.

At this moment I added this defaultproxy setting to my app.config to stop my application from trying to communicate through the proxy and instead ignore it.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false">
      <proxy/>
      <bypasslist/>
      <module/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

When I don't have this code in my app.config, my application will try to use the default internet options proxy.

So in order to have this switchable by a checkbox in a settings menu I will have to change these settings programatically.

I am aware of the fact that when I set the default proxy to a new webproxy that the application will ignore the internetoptions proxy.

`WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy();`

But I can't for the life of me figure out how I can set this back to the automatically detecting of proxy use, like before I inserted above defaultproxy settings in the app.config.

I am testing this by using a faulty proxy. This means that if I send an api request, the proxy can't be found and I receive a webexception. When I ignore the proxy with the app.config code, the request uses my normal internet connection, and returns API data.

It would really help me out if anyone could tell me how I can programatically set my application to ignore the proxy or, most importantly, to use the default auto detection settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the proxy back to the default proxy, you can use this static method

```
WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
```

see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webrequest.getsystemwebproxy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `WebRequest.DefaultProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();` did the trick. Thank you! Saved me a lot of head ache!